# taking 3*3 matrix input of single lineby user in python without using numpy

Tags: python-3.x

I am unable to make a code which can take 3x3 matrix .
Problem statement is: First line is 3x3 matrix .

I tried `arr=[[int(input()) for i in range(3)] for j in range(3)]`
which is getting an error.
when I wrote `arr=input()`
it returns :`[[1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1]]` which is completely string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
matrix = [list(map(int,input().split())) for i in range(3)]
```